# How can I console.log 2 arrays so that the countries match up with the cities?

Tags: javascript

```
const cities = [
    'Abu Dhabi',
    'Abuja',
    'Cairo',
    '???',
    'Amman',
    'Islamabad',
    'Tokyo',
    'Beirut',
    '???',
    'Ottowa',
    'New Delhi',
    'BrasÃ­lia'
];

const countries = [
    'UAE',
    'Nigeria',
    'Egypt',
    '???',
    'Jordan',
    'Pakistan',
    'Japan',
    'Lebanon',
    '???',
    'Canada',
    'India',
    'Brazil'
];
```

I created a for loop to iterate the cities but I am stuck on what to do next?

Comment: Please show us your attempt!

Comment: var counter=(countries)
var counter=(cities)
    if (cities) {
        countries.push(cities)
    }

Comment: I don't know if that is on the right track so if someone can help out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt there. Also add your expected result. Most questions here require a [mre]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, here a critical case is the length of both arrays must be the same and should be in a similar order to get the desired result. What I am doing here is just accessing both arrays at the same index.

```js
const cities = [
  'Abu Dhabi',
  'Abuja',
  'Cairo',
  '???',
  'Amman',
  'Islamabad',
  'Tokyo',
  'Beirut',
  '???',
  'Ottowa',
  'New Delhi',
  'BrasÃ­lia'
];

const countries = [
  'UAE',
  'Nigeria',
  'Egypt',
  '???',
  'Jordan',
  'Pakistan',
  'Japan',
  'Lebanon',
  '???',
  'Canada',
  'India',
  'Brazil'
];
for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  if (cities[i] === '???') {
    console.log('Oops')
  } else {
    console.log(cities[i], ': ', countries[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also do you know how I would replace all the '???' with it saying 'Oops' instead?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder12 If you are sure there will always be three question marks you can put a check there for that. I edited the answer. If it helps please upvote the answer.

Comment: Yea but I would want it so it doesn't show '???' in the console.log and instead it would show 'Oops' in its place. Sorry if that doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder12 I just updated the answer for that too

Comment: @BeginnerCoder12 you may replace that `if...else` statement with `console.log(cities[i] === '???' ? 'Oops' : cities[i] + ': ' + countries[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to group the data and console.log it

```js
const cities = [
    'Abu Dhabi',
    'Abuja',
    'Cairo',
    '???',
    'Amman',
    'Islamabad',
    'Tokyo',
    'Beirut',
    '???',
    'Ottowa',
    'New Delhi',
    'BrasÃ­lia'
];

const countries = [
    'UAE',
    'Nigeria',
    'Egypt',
    '???',
    'Jordan',
    'Pakistan',
    'Japan',
    'Lebanon',
    '???',
    'Canada',
    'India',
    'Brazil'
];
//build an array of object with country and city
const data = Array.from({length: Math.max(cities.length, countries.length)}, (v, i) => ({
  country: countries[i] || '',
  city: cities[i] || ''
}))

console.log(data)
```